# How to transfer label data to new controller label after label number is set with button

Tags: ios, swift, label

So how i transfer my ViewController label: totalPar to ThirdViewController label: totalPar5. And I want to transfer data that I have added there with my minus and plus buttons

Here is simulator pic that show what I want to transfer

[image]

My ThirdViewController is almost same as ViewController except prepare segue

Here is my ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var totalPar: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var plusminusPar: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currentPar: UILabel!


var totalPAR = Int()
var plusminusPAR = 0
var currentPAR = 0



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {

    totalPAR = Int(totalPar.text!)!
    self.totalPar.text = String(totalPAR - 1)

    plusminusPAR = Int(plusminusPar.text!)!
    self.plusminusPar.text = String(plusminusPAR - 1)

    currentPAR = Int(currentPar.text!)!
    self.currentPar.text = String(currentPAR - 1)
}

@IBAction func plusButton(_ sender: Any) {

    totalPAR = Int(totalPar.text!)!
    self.totalPar.text = String(totalPAR + 1)

    plusminusPAR = Int(plusminusPar.text!)!
    self.plusminusPar.text = String(plusminusPAR + 1)

    currentPAR = Int(currentPar.text!)!
    self.currentPar.text = String(currentPAR + 1)
}



@IBAction func Seuraava(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "next1", sender: Any?.self)
}


@IBAction func seiraava2(_ sender: Any) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seuraava2", sender: Any?.self)
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let thirdviewcontroller = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
    thirdviewcontroller.totalPAR5 = self.totalPAR
}


}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Transfer the text: `thirdviewcontroller.totalPAR5.text = self.totalPAR.text`

Comment: So `thirdviewcontroller.totalPar.text = self.totalPar.text` ? Not that I would ever write this but it seems it is what you are asking for..

Comment: You wrote this line: `thirdviewcontroller.totalPAR5 = self.totalPAR`

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani And then add in `viewDidLoad` following `self.totalPar.text = String(totalPAR - 1)`

Comment: @MaticOblak why should I add there -1 or +1, why only (totalPAR) not showing right amount

Comment: @Tonil92 Sorry, I didn't notice I pasted it with "- 1". The bottom point is he needs to update the label in view did load or somewhere if he is passing a value alone to a new view controller. Without that the value will be set but the label will not be updated.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yeh but, when I do that alone "totalPAR" without "+1" or "-1" it add value -1. Example I click 2 times button on firstviewcontroller and it add there number 2 on label. Then I go to secondviewcontroller there is only number 1 on label. OR I click 3 times and it show number 3 on firstviewcontroller label, there is on secondviewcontroller label only number 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the accepted answer and its comments you need to start improving your code and learn some concepts of data source in general.

For your case stop constantly converting string to integers to string. Choose one or the other:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var totalPAR: Int = 0
var plusminusPAR: Int = 0
var currentPAR: Int = 0
```

Do natural operations on actions and separate methods:

```
@IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: Any) {
    addToAll(valueToAdd: -1)
    refreshLabels()
}

private func addToAll(valueToAdd: Int) {
    totalPAR += valueToAdd
    plusminusPAR += valueToAdd
    currentPAR += valueToAdd
}

private func refreshLabels() {
    self.totalPar.text = String(totalPAR)
    self.plusminusPar.text = String(plusminusPAR) 
    self.currentPar.text = String(currentPAR)
}
```

Then you will have no issues calling

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let thirdviewcontroller = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {
        thirdviewcontroller.totalPAR = self.totalPAR
        thirdviewcontroller.plusminusPAR = self.plusminusPAR
        thirdviewcontroller.currentPAR = self.currentPAR
    }
}
```

Now if in both view controllers you call `refreshLabels` on `viewDidLoad` the values are successfully transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the variable in `ThirdViewController` and assign the value in prepare for segua and setup value to the label in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let thirdviewcontroller = segue.destination as! ThirdViewController
    thirdviewcontroller.totalPAR5 = self.totalPAR
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
  var totalPAR5 = 0
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.totalPar.text = "\(totalPAR5+1)" //You can calculate here like +1 or -1
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was it, but I needed add +1 to self.totalPar.text = "\(totalPAR5)" or it did add only 1 click

Comment: But if I don't add that +1 it only take 1 click. Example I click 2 times plus button, it only add 1 to thirdviewcontroller instead of 2